# How to check if the forward button is pushed or not

Tags: javascript, button, back, forward

I want to reload the page if user accesses through forward or back button,
so, is there any good way to check forward or back button is pushed, using javascript?

Yes, I've started to feel this is not good...
Actually, the page should be loaded many times through AJAX
so I don't want to use forward or back button for data consistency. 

Any ideas to solve this?
I think going forward or back to specific page is one idea.

Comment: No; the browser chrome isn't accessible by JavaScript. And with good reason. You can, possibly, use the `onbeforeunload` event, coupled with the history API to assess where the user's going, but since you can't `return false` or `event.preventDefault()` on `onbeforeunload` I can't imagine that this would help at all.

Comment: You don't need to do that at all, as the page is loaded again anyway.

Comment: Messing with what the user expects to see when using forward/back is a bad design choice.